# How do I solve "cp: cannot stat '/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf': No such file or directory"?

Tags: kubuntu

I'm getting this error

```
$ cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
cp: cannot stat '/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf': No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu. You should check [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions, since no one knows what you did before, which operating system you have etc.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the results of `kubeadm config print --kubeconfig string`

Answer (score 3):

The error is that a file you try to copy does not exist. The file you indicated is `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`. The error indicates that file does not exist.

To solve the problem, make sure you copy a file that is existing. If you want to copy a specific file, check that the file path you specify is accurate.